# Converting from LAContext.evaluatePolicy

Tags: swift, keychain, biometrics

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Local Authorization for biometric login.  However, I'm told that LocalAuthorization is unsafe and I need to move away from evaluatePolicy().  Is there a substitution for this or does it take a complete rewrite?

How do I use the keychain instead of Local Authorization?

Comment: How is it unsafe?

Comment: I'm told that a jailbroken phone can send the "OK" directly.

Comment: For example: "However, LocalAuthentication as a control can be trivially bypassed via hooking the APIs (e.g., via Cydia Substrate). For example, if the device is jailbroken, the attacker will be able to circumvent Local Authentication with ease and access the application as the user/victim."